# Sklearn NN clf.predict() always returns all 0's or all 1's?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm working on making a classifier using sklearn's MLPClassifier() function and have the following code:

```
def train_NN(self, trained_data_list, test_size=0.25):

    X = np.array([[7, 4], [3,7], [8,5], [2,3]])
    y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
    #oddly, printing 'X_train' yeilds the following: [[2 3] [3 7] [7 4]] and seems to have dropped my point [8 5]
    #printing 'y_train' yeilds the following: [0 1 0]


    self.clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-10, hidden_layer_sizes=(2, 2), activation = 'tanh', random_state=5, max_iter=10000, learning_rate_init = 0.1)
    
    self.clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print(self.clf.predict(np.atleast_2d([7,4])))  #returns 0 
    print(self.clf.predict(np.atleast_2d([3,7])))  #returns 0 
    print(self.clf.predict(np.atleast_2d([8,5])))  #returns 0 
    print(self.clf.predict(np.atleast_2d([2,3])))  #returns 0
```

My understanding here is that the 'X' array should correlate to the 'y' array. For example, giving clf.predict() the value [3,7] should return '1' since that's how they correlate in the way my NP arrays are defined. [8,5] should return '1', [2, 3] should return '0', etc.

I plan to make this on a much larger scale snd the data here is only to demo my problem. I'm new to the NN field so I'm sure I'm just missing something small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue in case anyone ever stumbles upon this. I was using the wrong activation function. Turns out 'logistic' works a lot better than 'tanh' in this type of classification scenario:

```
def train_NN(self, trained_data_list, test_size=0.25):

    X = np.array([[7, 4], [3,7], [8,5], [2,3]])
    y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

    self.clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-10, hidden_layer_sizes=(2, 2), activation = 'logistic', random_state=5, max_iter=10000, learning_rate_init = 0.1)

    self.clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print(self.clf.predict(np.atleast_2d([7,4])))  #returns 0
    print(self.clf.predict(np.atleast_2d([3,7])))  #returns 1 
    print(self.clf.predict(np.atleast_2d([8,5])))  #returns 1 
    print(self.clf.predict(np.atleast_2d([2,3])))  #returns 0
```